# SSE error in one code

Tags: c, vectorization, sse

I am new to SSE. I have the problem of transforming this code:

```
for (i = 0; i < m_; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < n_; j++) {
        (*vec)->data[i] += coeficientsI[j] * coefficientsII[j][i];
    }
}
```

into a SSE routine. I have this:

```
    __m128i vecMul, vecC, vecB, vsum;

    int B_aux[4];

    int multiple = n_/4;

    for (i = 0; i < m_; i++) {

            vsum = _mm_setzero_si128();

            for (j = 0; j < multiple ; j+=4) {

                    B_aux[0] = coefficientsII[j][i];
                    B_aux[1] = coefficientsII[j+1][i];
                    B_aux[2] = coefficientsII[j+2][i];
                    B_aux[3] = coefficientsII[j+3][i];

                    vecC = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i *)&((coefficientsI)[j] ));
                    vecB = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i *)&(B_aux) );

                    vecMul = _mm_mullo_epi32(vecC,vecB);

                    vsum = _mm_add_epi32(vsum,vecMul);
            }

            vsum = _mm_hadd_epi32(vsum, vsum);
            vsum = _mm_hadd_epi32(vsum, vsum);

            (*vec)->data[i] += _mm_extract_epi32(vsum, 0);

            for ( ; j < n_ ; j++)
                    (*vec)->data[i] += coefficientsI[j] * coefficientsII[j][i];
    }
```

But this don't work. Where is the problem?

I want to vectorize the kernel because it was detected as a hotspot. However, it faisl... the result is wrong.

Thanks

Comment: What error are you getting? As it is, there isn't enough information for us to answer.

Comment: Hi! thanks for the answer. the results in the vectors are different.

Comment: Then step through with a debugger to see when the value starts to diverge from what you expect it to be.

Comment: Looks like you're computing a matrix-vector product.  People spent lots of time optimizing stuff like this.  You may want to take a look at BLAS libraries.  Also, matrix-vector products are typically memory bound -- vectorization won't make it faster.

Comment: The values of B_aux are not the same as in the first non-vectorized code;

Comment: Is there any optimized library that I should use ExP?

Comment: Use `int multiple = n & (-4)` and you will get the correct result.

Answer (score 1):

Your `multiple` cut is wrong.  You divide by four but still increment by four then when you clean up in the final loop it's off by a factor of four.  This is easy to fix.  Define multiple as

```
int multiple = n & (-4);
```

If you use your definition of multiple you have to do

```
for (j = 0; j < multiple ; j++) {
    B_aux[0] = coefficientsII[4*j][i];
    B_aux[1] = coefficientsII[4*j+1][i];
    B_aux[2] = coefficientsII[4*j+2][i];
    B_aux[3] = coefficientsII[4*j+3][i];
    vecC = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i *)&((coefficientsI)[4*j] ));
    //..

for (j*=4 ; j < n_ ; j++)
    (*vec)->data[i] += coefficientsI[j] * coefficientsII[j][i];
```

See my example here [Manually vectorized code 10x slower than auto optimized - what I did wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22320814/manually-vectorized-code-10x-slower-than-auto-optimized-what-i-did-wrong/22454638#22454638)

Note, that your code is not cache friendly when you access `coefficientsII[j][i]`.  If you can generate the transpose coefficientsII_T and access as `coefficientsII_T[i][j]` you probably will see better results.